# Jetpack Compose - Image antialiasing not as smooth as native ImageView when scaled

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm refactoring a screen to use jetpack compose.  It had an `ImageView` that sits over the top of the background containing a large 1920x795dp PNG image (mdpi and hdpi buckets) which gets scaled down.  After changing to use an `Image` it now has noticably jaggier edges.

`ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-90dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_swoosh"/>
```

[image: ImageView]

[image: ImageView]

`Image`:

```
Image(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .offset(y = 90.dp)
        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_swoosh),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
)
```

[image: Compose Image]

[image: Compose Image]

Drilling into the source of `Image`, it uses `AndroidPaint` which supposedly has it enabled:

```
internal fun makeNativePaint() =
    android.graphics.Paint(android.graphics.Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
```

If I wrap `ImageView` in `AndroidView` the problem is not present.  I can also verify that it is positioned and sized exactly the same as the `Image` version, but it is anti-aliased correctly.

```
AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .offset(y = 90.dp)
        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
    factory = {
        ImageView(it).apply {
            scaleType = android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY
            setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_swoosh)
        }
    }
)
```

If I remove scaling with `contentScale = ContentScale.None` the image is also smooth, so it does appear to be due to being scaled down.  Removing `contentScale` entirely shows the same problem because the image is automatically scaled down to fit the view.

Edit: If I remove the hdpi variant it also becomes smooth!